# Collision between sphere and rounded cone faster?

Tags: c++, optimization, collision, primitive

Is there a faster way to do this?

I have a routine that detects if a sphere collides with a rounded cone:

```
bool Math3D::DoesSphereIntersectRoundedCone(Vector spherePos, float sphereRadius, Vector coneStart, float coneStartRadius, Vector coneEnd, float coneEndRadius)
{
    float aPercent=GetClosestPointOnLinePercent(spherePos,coneStart,coneEnd);
    float aRad=InterpolateLinear(coneStartRadius,coneEndRadius,aPercent);
    Vector aPos=InterpolateLinear(coneStart,coneEnd,aPercent);

    if (DistanceSquared(spherePos,aPos)<=SQUARED(sphereRadius+aRad)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

When checking collision with a grid of spheres and plotting each positive collision, I get the correct result:

[image: Collision points mapped]

Comment: I think very few will understand what the code you posted actually does, and even fewer will be able to suggest any improvements. The code is incomplete.

Comment: I suspect that `GetClosestPointOnLinePercent` loses some information that must be regained with the first `InterpolateLinear`.  Namely, "what are the coordinates of the point?"  Whatever library is providing these functions, see if there's a `GetClosestPointOnLine` function that returns a `Vector`.

Comment: You seem to be passing your `Vector` values around by value. That might result in unnecessary copying, depending on the implementation.

Comment: I't up to benchmarking, but condition seems could be like `DistanceAbs(spherePos,aPos)<=sphereRadius+aRad`

Comment: @Renat a `DistanceSquared` function tends to be a full `sqrt` faster than a `Distance`.  It's faster to square one side than to sqrt the other.

Comment: Maybe you can learn something from ray-marching algorithms, they usually are good at providing equations for distances to objects. Like maybe this one : https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tdXGWr.  You will have an intersection if the distance is smaller then the radius of your spere.

Comment: Hi @PepijnKramer, your link eventually took me to this page: https://github.com/stonkpunk/my-npm-modules/blob/main/round-cone-distance/index.js ... which works!  The only fly in the ointment is, the squared version there doesn't work (even the sample seems to have it wrong??) and I'd sure like to lose that sqrt, which I don't need!

Answer (score 1):

With assist from @PepijnKramer, I managed to find the "simplest" version of this, which has only one sqrt.  Posting it here for posterity:

```
float Math3D::DistanceToRoundedCone(Vector thePos, Vector coneStart, float coneStartRadius, Vector coneEnd, float coneEndRadius)
{
    Vector aV1=thePos-coneStart;
    Vector aV2=coneEnd-coneStart;
    float aPercent=_clamp(0.0f,(aV1.mX*aV2.mX+aV1.mY*aV2.mY+aV1.mZ*aV2.mZ) / (aV2.mX*aV2.mX+aV2.mY*aV2.mY+aV2.mZ*aV2.mZ),1.0f);
    Vector aV3=aV1-(aPercent*aV2);
    return aV3.Length()-coneStartRadius-(coneEndRadius-coneStartRadius)*aPercent;
}
```